# What would be a reasonable response to this take that we shouldn't ponder abstract propositions about the meaning of life?

Tags: existentialism, nihilism, meaning-of-life, absurdism

X says: “That moment when you realise that you've spent your entire life endlessly pondering abstract propositions about the meaning of life instead of actually feeling like you've led a meaningful life”

Comment: sounds like a loaded question. First of all you provided someone's opinion. Whether it's stupid or not is a matter of discussion. Moreover if it;s a personal  opinion on a very subjective matter it's not very sound to label it stupid at all, regardless your own take on it

Comment: How can you make a "reasonable response" if you have already tarred it with 'stupid'? You are being **unreasonable**.

Comment: What exactly leads you to the conclusion that X's view is stupid? Since you already reached that conclusion, it seems that either the premises underlying your conclusion are flawed or you just need a suggestion on how to formulate them. But first you need to at least outline how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: The telescope turns, and now you are under a microscope. Your views view you. The reasonable response would be to let go of all views.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion that one shouldn't spend their entire life pondering abstract propositions about the meaning of life is not without merit. It reminds us to not only think about life but also to live it. However, it doesn't necessarily mean that contemplating such abstract propositions is meaningless or unimportant.

Here's a potential response to such a viewpoint:

---

While I agree that life is meant to be lived and experienced, I also believe there's value in pondering its abstract propositions. Contemplation about life's meaning can offer important insights and guide our actions. It can help us understand our values, our purpose, and what we find meaningful, which can then inform our decisions and actions.

Furthermore, contemplating abstract propositions and leading a meaningful life are not mutually exclusive. One can reflect on the meaning of life and still engage in meaningful activities. In fact, such contemplation can often enhance our experiences and our appreciation of life.

The key is balance. Spending all our time in abstract contemplation, to the extent that we neglect to live our lives, can certainly be a problem. But so can mindlessly going through life without ever pausing to reflect on its meaning.

Therefore, rather than avoiding contemplation of life's abstract propositions, perhaps we should strive to find a balance between contemplation and action. By doing so, we can lead lives that are both thoughtful and full of meaningful experiences.